Can't build IPA file with Flutter on Bash due to integration test package
I'm trying to build IPA file using Flutter through Bash. But it return error
building for 'iOS', but linking in dylib (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.tbd) built for 'macOS macCatalyst zippered(macOS/Catalyst)'

So I trie printing debug log using --verbose Ans here is the result.
Ld /Users/tcbdevbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Techswop-hcgdxzbupbdesybvyqnrorjdyarb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/integration_test.framework/integration_test normal (in target 'integration_test' from project 'Pods')
                cd /Users/tcbdevbuild/Documents/trade-in-mobile-app/ios/Pods
                /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -Xlinker -reproducible -target arm64-apple-ios15.5 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.0.sdk -Os -L/Users/tcbdevbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Techswop-hcgdxzbupbdesybvyqnrorjdyarb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/EagerLinkingTBDs/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/tcbdevbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Techswop-hcgdxzbupbdesybvyqnrorjdyarb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/integration_test -F/Users/tcbdevbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Techswop-hcgdxzbupbdesybvyqnrorjdyarb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/EagerLinkingTBDs/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/tcbdevbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Techswop-hcgdxzbupbdesybvyqnrorjdyarb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/integration_test -F/Users/tcbdevbuild/Documents/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios-release/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64 -filelist /Users/tcbdevbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Techswop-hcgdxzbupbdesybvyqnrorjdyarb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/integration_test.build/Objects-normal/arm64/integration_test.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/integration_test.framework/integration_test -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/tcbdevbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Techswop-hcgdxzbupbdesybvyqnrorjdyarb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/integration_test.build/Objects-normal/arm64/integration_test_lto.o -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework UIKit -framework Flutter -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/tcbdevbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Techswop-hcgdxzbupbdesybvyqnrorjdyarb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/integration_test.build/Objects-normal/arm64/integration_test_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/tcbdevbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Techswop-hcgdxzbupbdesybvyqnrorjdyarb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/integration_test.framework/integration_test
            ld: building for 'iOS', but linking in dylib (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.A.tbd) built for 'macOS macCatalyst zippered(macOS/Catalyst)'
            clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The issue doesn't happen in zsh and I did made sure that both zsh and Bash use the same env PATH. Gitlab-Runner use only Bash so I kinda need a fix to run CI/CD pipeline. Anyone know how to fix it?

I throw my env path from zsh and bash env > bash/zsh_path.txt into ChatGPT and ask it where the differences was. It turns out that, for some reason, Bash env path have SDKROOT and LIBRARY_PATH default to MacOSX library in Bash. both path did not exist in zsh. So the way I manage to solve it is going into .bashrc nano ~/.bashrc and just add these 2 lines on the top.
unset SDKROOT
unset LIBRARY_PATH

I don't know if this is Xcode doing or what exactly, if anyone know more, I'm more than welcome for further explanation!
